# Combine set values into single set

Tags: python

I have the following dict object:

```
obj = {
  'US': set(...),
  'FR': set(...),
  'BE': set(...)
}
```

How would I combine it into a single set? Currently I'm doing it the verbose way of:

```
items = set(list(obj['US']) + list(obj['FR']) + list(obj['BE']))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An efficient way is with set.union(*obj.values())

For example:

```
obj = {
  'US': set([1,2,3]),
  'FR': set([3,4,5]),
  'BE': set([5,6,7])
}

set.union(*obj.values())
Out[35]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user `chain` here:

```
 from itertools import chain
 set(chain(*obj.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly neater way would be to use the `|` operator:

```
items = obj['US'] | obj['FR'] | obj['BE']
```

Answer (score 0):

The set type supports the `|` operator to perform unions. It also supports the `.union` method. So what you want is probably

```
items = set.union(*obj.values())
```

or

```
items = obj['US'] | obj['FR'] | obj['BE']
```

if you want to be explicit.